# Spring Webflow: Can subflows have nested subflows?

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I have an odd bug where I call a subflow from a subflow. Before wasting anyone's time with the details I would like to posit a simple question.

Does Spring Webflow allow multiple nested subflows? If the answer is "no" then any further detail in this question would be moot.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to short question is:
yes